# drawn or drawn in

Tags: word-choice

I have a figure and some edges are plotted for convenience.
So I want to write a caption like

> "Auxiliary edges are **drawn in**"

But I'm confused about the **in**.

As a non native speaker, **drawn in** sounds much clearer than just **drawn**, but I'm worried about false friends.

Can I use **drawn in** here, or do people expect i.e. a colour or place to follow the **in**?

And if it's ok to use **in**, which would be more natural **drawn** or **drawn in**?

Comment: "Auxiliary edges are rendered"

Comment: I would like: Auxiliary edges _have been_ drawn in.

Answer (score 1):

There are almost 15 000 000 Google hits for "paint in the edges", eg:

> I also paint in the edges of the base at this stage [ – ] it makes the
>   whole thing look so much tidier when it[']s finished.

This shows that at least one related verb takes the particle / adverb  (jury's out on this) 'in', which gives the sense 'add a necessary/desired part of the whole drawing / painting ...'. (Note that 'I also paint the edges of the base at this stage' has a different meaning, unavailable with 'draw'.)

'Draw in' *can* be used to mean 'add as a required part of the drawing' (eg

> Draw in the trees using a dabbing motion with the side of the knife to
>   create a bark look.

and

> Next, we draw in the flowers and the jug.

from the internet), but perhaps a simple 'added', 'or 'added to the drawing', sounds less junior-school register. Here, 'the plotted points are now connected to show the edges' might work.

A slight complication with 'draw in' is that it has other meanings, as a true multi-word verb. See [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/draw-in). The word 'in' is made to do many jobs in English – it's little wonder people get confused. And it's such a *small* word!

Answer (score -2):

Well, **Drawn** is basically

> past form of Draw

and comming to your query its always *rational to **use DRAWN IN*** as it means to draw an outline of something and also it sounds normal if you are not considering the time frame(I would always use **drawn in**).

Comment: http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/draw.html